# Is it possible to JSON Serialize a property marked as [Ignore] automatically

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a (simplified) object like so:

```
public class Contact 
{
    [Ignore]
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

and I serialize and deserialise the object to create a deep copy clone (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/2987066) like so:

```
var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
};

var clone = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact, deserializeSettings);

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(clone);
```

but the property does not get copied across

Is it possible to serialise properties marked as `[Ignore]`. Maybe using `JsonSerializerSettings` or do I need to mark it as `[JSONProperty]`

Comment: is it the attribute really ignore or jsonignore or ignoredatamemeber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way to do this is add the ignored fields back:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(clone).Name=contact.Name
```

But the point of using ignore is so that it doesn't get serialized.

Another option is to specify a custom contract resolver in jsonserializersettings:

```
 var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
                ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver()
            };
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm

```
public class DynamicContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        //property.HasMemberAttribute = true;
        property.Ignored = false;

        //property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
        //{
        //    return true;
        //};

        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the `DynamicContractResolver` and it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Out of interrest why are there commented out lines in the `ContractResolver`? Do those need to be uncommented or just removed?

Comment: You can remove them, those are just examples of what you could do.